# How can I use PowerShell to get the providers information from web.config for all sites in IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis, ntlm

I have a need to identify IIS sites that allow NTLM authentication across all hosts in my enterprise. PowerShell is already installed on every host, so PowerShell seems like the obvious solution.

I haven't spent a lot of time with PowerShell, but this is the code I've come up with so far. It appears to properly iterate through my site list and I can get the providers element, but I'm not able to check the values of the **add** element's attributes.

I also tried reviewing other questions and answers, using the "similar questions" feature.

Here's the code

```ps
$site_list = Get-IISSite
foreach($site in $site_list)
{
    $ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication")
    foreach ($attribute in $ConfigSection.Attributes)
    {
        if($attribute.Name -eq "enabled")
        {
            Write-Host $site.Name : $attribute.Name : $attribute.Value
        }

    }
    
    foreach($element in $ConfigSection.ChildElements)
    {
        
        if ($element.ElementTagName -eq "providers")
        {
            Write-Host ChildElements.Count : $element.ChildElements.Count
            $element.Attributes
            $element|fl
            Write-Host Attributes Count : $element.Attributes.Count
            #$elem_attributes = $element.Attributes
            
            foreach ($elem_attr in $elem_attributes)
            {
                Write-Host $elem_attr
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My output of format-list shows a child element with the ElementTagName of **add** with an attribute of Value. However when I show the Count() of the the Attributes property, it shows 0. I think the OOP terminology and the XML element and properties are confusing, so I might not have some of my terms correct. Any help or guidance anyone can offer would be helpful.

Here's an example output of the format-list for the element.

```
Attributes      : {value}
ChildElements   : {}
ElementTagName  : add
IsLocallyStored : True
Methods         : 
RawAttributes   : {[value, Negotiate]}
Schema          : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementSchema

Attributes      : {value}
ChildElements   : {}
ElementTagName  : add
IsLocallyStored : True
Methods         : 
RawAttributes   : {[value, NTLM]}
Schema          : Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still using the older WebAdministration cmdlets:

```
Get-WebSite | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Output $_.Name
    Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$($_.Name)"  -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/providers/*" -name "." | Format-Table Value
}
```

this will also show providers inherited from the server level.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this took care of me. I was able to check all my hosts using SCCM in a matter of seconds and get all the insecure providers.